# auto-renew package for subcriptions of app on App Store

Tags: auto-renewing

"We noticed that the different durations of your auto-renewable subscriptions were created as separate in-app purchase products, rather than as different durations within the same subscription group."

I got this notice when submit app on App Store. I dont really understand "separate" mean.
Can I devide the packages into many duaration, and each duration has different content?
Or the content must be similar between duration?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they want you to group all subscriptions, granting users access to the same content but with different durations, into the same subscription group.

Comment: So content in one group is the same with different duaration while content in each group are different, right? Can I set group 1 have content X and group 2 have content X+Y? (group 2 content involves group 1)

Comment: I recommend you to read this article: https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/ios-subscription-groups-explained-8c5b8325d4ab